# Need hints/resources to solve this system of equations (seems like a loop)

Tags: calculus, derivatives

$\begin{cases}
x=1+\ln y \\
y=1+\ln z \\
z=1+\ln x
\end{cases}$

I've tried taking the derivative with respect to each variable on the RHS, i.e.

$\dfrac{dx}{dy}=\dfrac{1}{y},\quad\dfrac{dy}{dz}=\dfrac{1}{z},\quad\dfrac{dz}{dx}=\dfrac{1}{x}$.

I also happened to notice the solution $x=z=y=1$ by guessing it.

$\begin{eqnarray}
x = 1+\ln(1) = 1 \\
y = 1+\ln(1) = 1 \\
z = 1+\ln(1) = 1
\end{eqnarray}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

plugging the second equation in the first one we obtain
$x=1+\ln(1+\ln(z))$
with the third equation we get
$x=1+\ln(1+\ln(1+\ln(x)))$
thus you have got an equation in one variable
$x=1$ is the only real solution of this equation

Comment: To finish, you only need that $0<\ln x< x-1$ for $x>1$ and $0>\ln x>x-1$ for $0<x<1$.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen I'm sorry but I have to ask; how does that show that the only solution is $x=y=z=1$?