# Numerical approximation, or is there a better way? $x=1+\ln(1+\ln(1+\ln(x)))$

Tags: calculus, approximation

Don't have enough reputation to post on [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1026381/need-hints-resources-to-solve-this-system-of-equations-seems-like-a-loop/1026386) but is there any way of calculating the following?

$x=1+\ln(1+\ln(1+\ln(x)))$

Comment: Why not just plug in $x=1$ and see that the equation holds?

Comment: try $x=1+\log x$ first, then two logs

Comment: @DanielR That finds a solution,  but short of showing monotonicity on the difference of the two,  it doesn't a priori show all solutions, at least to my eye.

Comment: @WillJagy If I let $x=1+\log x$ that will just make the expression have more $\log$ expressions in it, making it more difficult, to me.

Comment: Ahhh. I always mean $\log$ to be what you are typing as ln. It is true, there is need in science for log based 10 and, more recently, log base 2, but in number theory and analysis it is always base $e.$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider $$f(x)=x-(1+\ln(1+\ln(1+\ln(x)))).$$ It is

$$f'(x)=1-\frac{1}{1+\ln(1+\ln(x))}\cdot \frac{1}{1+\ln (x)}\cdot \frac 1x=\frac{(1+\ln(1+\ln(x)))(1+\ln x)x-1}{(1+\ln(1+\ln(x)))(1+\ln x)x}.$$

If $x\in(e^{1/e-1},1)$ then $f'(x)<0$ (that is, $f$ is strictly decreasing in $(e^{1/e-1},1)$) and if $x\in(1,\infty)$ it is $f'(x)>0$ (that is, $f$ is strictly increasing in $(1,\infty)).$ Since $f(1)=0$ we can conclude that $x=1$ is the only solution of the equation.

Comment: Glad someone went through the monotonicity argument for uniqueness :).

Comment: You are right about it being $f'(x) < 0$ in the interval $]0,1[$. How did you know about that though? Was that with the help of a calculator or is there something I don't see?

Comment: If $x<1$ then $\ln x<0.$ Thus the numerator of $f'$ is negative since it is the product of two positive numbers smaller than $1$ minus $1.$ However, the denominator is positive. Note that for $\ln(1+\ln(1+ln (1+\ln x)))$ to exists it must be $1+\ln(1+ln (1+\ln x))>0.$ In a similar way $\ln(1+ln (1+\ln x))$ exists and so $1+ln (1+\ln x)>0.$